# about convex function counterexample

Tags: real-analysis

Proposition) If a function $f : [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfies two conditions that

(1) $f$ is continuous

(2) $f(\frac{x+y}{2}) \le \frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$ for every $x$, $y$

then $f$ is convex function.

I already know the proof of above proposition.
My question is how can I find counterexample without condition (1). 
That is, I want to find non-convex function $f$ satisfying condition (2).

Thank you:)

Comment: Have you tried going through the proof and see where you need (1), and then cooking up a counterexample based on that?

Comment: See _Inequalities_ by Hardy, Littlewood, Pólya, 3.20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is not a correct counterexample, but I suppose it may provide some ideas...

Consider Dirichlet function
    \begin{eqnarray}
 D(x)=\left\{
 \begin{aligned}
 1\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x\in \mathbb{Q}\\
 0\ \ \ \ \ x\in [0,1]-\mathbb{Q}
 \end{aligned}
 \right.
 \end{eqnarray}
D(x) is defined on [0,1], and is nowhere continuous. Of course it's not a convex function.

When $x_1$, $x_2\in \mathbb{Q}$, we have $f(\dfrac{x_1+x_2}{2})=1$, and $\dfrac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)}{2}=1$. Similarly, for $x_1 \in \mathbb{Q}$, $x_2\in[0,1]-\mathbb{Q}$, we have left$=0$ and right=$\dfrac12$.

But for $x_1$, $x_2\in [0,1]-\mathbb{Q}$ we have left$=0$ or $1$ and right$=0$.
The third situation does not satisfy (2). That's my problem, and I mistook it yesterday. I tried to improve it but failed.

Comment: Notice that if (2) is satisfied, then for any $p\in \mathbb{Q}$, we have $f(px_1+(1-p)x_2)\leq pf(x_1)+(1-p)f(x_2)$

Comment: What if $x=1/\pi, y = 1/3-1/\pi?$

Comment: Yes, you're right. I made a mistake for the situation when both $x_1$ and $x_2$ are not in $\mathbb{Q}$...

Comment: Thank you for answer. Thought your example include error, your answer give me some motivate and strategy to attack the problem!

Comment: Well,you can refer to this: https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2010/06/29/convex-continuous-jensens/

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you're not going to be able to come up with any *nice* construction that works as a counterexample.  In particular, I think you need to invoke the axiom of choice to create a suitable counterexample.

For example, any discontinuous solution to [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_functional_equation) will work here.

---

In particular, I would say that (2) is just enough to tell you that $f$ acts as a convex function when restricted to any coset of $\Bbb Q$ as a subset of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: You are right. I delete my silly answer.

Comment: @JeanMarie I saw that you did, no worries. It'd be interesting if I were wrong here.